# how can we mock a private class filed which is used by functions

Tags: java, static, mockito

For example, i have a class:

```
Class A {

    private final BBB bbb = new BBB(CCC.INSTANCE.getInstance(DDDUtils.getId()));

}
```

bbb is being used in some functions of the class. How can we mock bbb in test functions?
i am using Mockit.

I tried:

```
@Mock
private BBB bbb;
```

but didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to mock it, e.g. is `BBB` slow or performs IO? If not, why can't you use the real one? If it does, then change the design of your classes to be testable, e.g. by using dependency injection

Comment: hi knittl, could you provide example for "use real one"? Or you initialize exactly the same BBB bbb = new BBB(... in the test class?

Comment: There is no need to initialize a new one, your field initializer is already initializing the real one. Just do `new A()` in your class and write the tests (a new `BBB` is created automatically by A). My original question is: do you _have to_ mock it? _Why_ do you want to mock BBB? There must be a reason for it

Comment: without mocking it, i got error during unit test. Failed to load it.